# Python code to parse time argument from command line to print specific lines of crontab file

Tags: python, datetime, cron, command-line-arguments, criteria

I'm writing a Python program that takes the time argument from the command line, compares it with the crontab.txt file and if the time value is same or after the time specified in the command line, It prints out the line of crontab.txt what meets the criteria.

crontab file content

```
50,11,3,Sagar,/home/Sagar/backup 
30,17,4,sahara,/home/sahara/data/backup
0,0,6,root,/usr/bin/find / -name a.out
```

And python code built looks like below

```
elif(args.time):
    if contents ==[]:
        print('No crontab lines for time specified')
    else:
        flag=False
        for line in contents:
            second_col = line.split(',')[2]
            if( args.time == second_col.split(':')[-1]):
                if(flag==False):
                    print('Output:')
                print(line)
                flag = True
        if(not flag):
            print('No crontab lines for time specified')
            
elif(args.time):
    if contents == [] :
        print("No command lines for the specified time")
    else:
        for line in contents:
            t1 = line.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]
            if args.time == 'M' and int(t1) == datetime.datetime.now:
                print(line)
            elif args.time == 'H' and int(t1) == datetime.datetime.now:
                print(line)
            elif args.time == 'D' and int(t1) == datetime.datetime.now:
                    print(line)
            else:
                print("No command lines for the specified time")
```

Here is how output looks like
[Sagar]$ ./crontab_summary.py -t 0:0:1 crontab.txt Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/Crontab/./crontab_summary.py", line 95, in  main()

I would like to take values 0:0:1 from the command line, compare those with the crontab.txt file lines and see if their is any line that either matches or is higher than the time provided in command line. If yes, print that line as the output. If not, print the error message (no command lines for the specified time).

How to write this code or fix the existing code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include sample input and your actual output.  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: How to fix your code to do what? What is the exact problem?

Comment: Thank you. I have added the missing details in my question.